# CSS border confusion

Tags: html, css

Just confused as to why when hover with border-bottom the border plays well with the content but when changed to border-top it pushes down the content.

Here's the code...

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;    
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow; 
} 


li a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: .2s all linear;
}


li a:hover {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 50px solid lightskyblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
  <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#peace">peace</a></li>
      <li><a href="#love">love</a></li>  
  </ul>
```

Comment: Put the height on li only, not on li a

Comment: li a { border-top: 50px solid transparent; } li a:hover { border-top: 50px solid lightskyblue; } this wont create jerk

Comment: I got say, I know this is not intended, but this effect looks kind cool!

Answer (score 1):

I would change a bit the structure to use an overlay instead of borders. And without the need to use fixed heights.

From what I see the border-top issue is actually the expected behaviour. Both `border-top` and `border-bottom` push content downwards, but since you are using `box-sizing: border-box` and the bottom border is already underneath the text you won't see the content go down.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    width: auto;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: yellow; 
} 

li a{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
}

li a .overlay{
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    transition: .2s all linear;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

li a:hover .overlay {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#peace">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            peace
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#love">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            love
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll take a look at that in morning.

Answer (score 0):

See `border-top` adds the height in the element from top to downward direction and `border-bottom` add height from bottom also in downward direction...so applying the `border-top` will always push your text to down

Actually you have applied `box-sizing: border-box` with `height: 50px` to that element...it means element's border will not affect the height of that element if any `height` value is specified...

As MDN web docs says

> [***border-box*** tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for width and height. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

If you remove `height` from the element you will see that `border-bottom` will add below text because no `height` value is defined...

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  /* height: 50px; */
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: .2s all linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li a:hover {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 50px solid lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#peace">peace</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And yes I got that too. But I'm still confused, sorry. Just wondering why when height is determined border-bottom does not push the content out upward and but border-top will push content out downward. I'm missing something incredibly simple ...sigh.

Comment: @paulrevere `border-bottom` adds height from bottom so it will not not push the content to up...here `box-sizing:border-box` plays a important role here....it tells the element that border will not affect the height of the element if height is specified...

Comment: @paulrevere try to remove the `box-sizing:border-box` in your question with and you will see that the `border-bottom` will increase the height down not to up

Comment: Thanks again! So why is it that although both borders do show within the height of the element ... border-top pushes the content out and border-bottom does not push the content out?

Comment: @paulrevere because border-bottom added below of the text in downward direction not upward direction and border-top added top of the text also in downward direction thats why its pushing the content down....

Comment: Thanks taking the time, Bhuwan. it's a bit clearer. So the content will always be pushed down and out by border-top in my current code.